# How to inject component router in Angular 1.5?

Tags: angularjs, angular-new-router, angularjs-components

I'm working with Angular 1.5 and trying to migrate from using ui-router in 1.4 to the new Component Router in 1.5.

However, when I update to 1.5, I don't see a way to inject '$router' into my configuration.

I know I can download angular_1_router.js from this repository: https://github.com/brandonroberts/angularjs-component-router

But isn't the new router supposed to be included in 1.5?

Sorry, there doesn't appear to be much documentation on this. There's only the [outdated docs](https://angular.github.io/router/) that refer to Angular 1.4 and the [Angular 2.0 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

When I try using the angular_1_router.js file, I get an `$injector:modulerr` when trying to use 'ngComponentRouter', so I haven't been able to go that route as a workaround.

Comment: Update: Component router is planned for 1.5.1

Answer (score 2):

The new router is in a separate JavaScript file. You have to load it in your index.html file. I am not entirely certain if the 2.0 router works as is with 1.5 or not, but I believe that is supposed to be the case.

It's available here:

Just loading the js file should be sufficient, no injection is required.

The latest dev guide is here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router

I am currently weighing migrating from ui-router to the new router but finding scant information available. This article looks to be somewhat helpful: http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2015/03/30/horror-migrating-angular-ui-router-to-angular-new-router.aspx, but it's quite dated.

Comment: You forgot to place the link at "It's available here:"

Comment: Right, it'll be an application dependency like any other. E.g.:

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngComponentRouter']), but make sure you're loading the js script for the router first

Comment: I came here looking for the .js file.  Is there really no way to download it without using node?

Comment: It's been depracated. You're better off going with UI-Router for 1.x projects.